# When are pointers to the same object equal?

Tags: c

For two pointers `a` and `b` that both point to the same object or function, under which circumstances do the C standards guarantee that `a == b`? Are there any platforms on which `a != b` could hold when `a` and `b` point to the same object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.5.9 Equality operators from N1548 Committee Draft — December 2, 2010 ISO/IEC 9899:201x)

> 6 Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers,
>   **both are pointers to the same object** (including a pointer to an object
>   and a subobject at its beginning) **or function**, both are pointers to
>   one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a
>   pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a
>   pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to
>   immediately follow the first array object in the address space.109)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Someone told me that Intel added language to C so that `a != b` could hold even if `a` and `b` point to different objects. Which C standard are you quoting?

Comment: @FUZxxl- `a!=b` will hold only when if an and b point to different objects. I think you mis-typed!

Comment: @FUZxxl  I quoted the following document N1548 Committee Draft — December 2, 2010 ISO/IEC 9899:201x